# How can i specify the Working directory from bash script

Tags: java, bash

I want to run my java algorithm from bash script. When i run my program from `Netbeans` i can specify my `Working directory` from application. So, how can i specify the `Working directory` from bash script ?

Comment: use `$PWD`,the environment variable for present working directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bash, you can just cd to the directory you'd like to work from. So, for example, if your app lives in ~/bin/app.jar, you'd have something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

WORKING_DIR=$HOME/lib # whichever directory you want to work from
cd $WORKING_DIR
java -jar ~/bin/app.jar
```

The trick is using an absolute path to your executable, or in this case, an absolute path to your Jar file.